# How to Customise Text Animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, animation, text

i am working on Flutter Text Animation.Its a Scaler text animation.
The thing i wanna do is, i just wants to Make sure that the 'text' appear only once,and stay that way.So that i can tap that 'Text'  to get transfered to a new page.Not just appearing fading and re-appearing again.Can i anyone suggest me the code?

```
[AnimatedTextKit(animatedTexts:[
              ScaleAnimatedText(
                " Rehman",
              textStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 85.0,
              fontFamily: "MonteCarlo",
              color: Colors.white
              )
              )
            ],
```

Comment: [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit) contains a collection of some cool and awesome text animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try these 3 parameters?

```
isRepeatingAnimation set to false
or repeatForever set to false
or totalRepeatCount set to 1 or 0
```

or Just customize your own transition like:

```
class _ScaleTransitionState extends State<ScaleTransition>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this, value: 0);
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeIn);

    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: _animation,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Test',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yess, But the animation stops at the faded moment...I want the animation to stop at the exact moment where it just shown up from dark back ground, and be like this..It will be a great help if you suggest some sollution.